# WPF DataGrid sometimes displays wrong color or font

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WCF app that logs messages.  The messages are displayed in a `DataGrid`.  Each row contains four columns for time, type (i.e. Debug, Error, Warning…), namespace (e.g. `System.Threading`), and the message itself.

Each row is displayed in a color based on type.  For instance, red for Error.  The text for all information (rows/columns) in the `DataGrid` is to be displayed in the same font.

In the XAML, you can see that I have specified the font settings and type colors in the `DataGrid.RowStyle`.  ‘Settings’ is a class that contains properties for the font settings and colors.

My problem is that every now and then a row is displayed in the wrong color and/or font.  Can someone explain what is going on?

Is a style the best way to specify the font settings and colors?  Note that I wish these settings to be dynamic so the user can change them at runtime.  Any suggestions on style or implementation are welcome.

```
<DataGrid Name="MessagesGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Setters>
            <EventSetter Event="Control.RequestBringIntoView" Handler="RequestBringIntoViewHandler"/>

            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Settings.MessageListFont.FontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Settings.MessageListFont.Size}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Settings.MessageListFont.Weight}" />
        </Style.Setters>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <!--colors for different types-->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Debug">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Settings.DebugBrush}"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Error">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Settings.ErrorBrush}"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Fatal">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Settings.FatalBrush}"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Info">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Settings.InfoBrush}"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Trace">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Settings.TraceBrush}"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Warn">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Settings.WarningBrush}"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>

<DataGrid.Columns>
    <!--using converter for some fields in case one or more are null.  
                    if null, then display a string (MissingFieldString) indicating it was not in the message-->

    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NullableTypeConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Time" />
                <Binding ElementName="MessagesGrid" Path="DataContext.MissingFieldString" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn>

    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NullableTypeConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Type" />
                <Binding ElementName="MessagesGrid" Path="DataContext.MissingFieldString" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn>

    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Namespace">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NullableTypeConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Namespace" />
                <Binding ElementName="MessagesGrid" Path="DataContext.MissingFieldString" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn>

    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" Binding="{Binding Message}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Did you change the values of the source properties dynamically when you see the wrong colour or when does this happen exactly?

Comment: This happens randomly.  It does not happen when a color/font is changed, my users rarely use that feature.  It is not uncommon for there to be a burst of messages to display - maybe a few dozen in a second.